# MySQL select only one name

Tags: mysql

I need to display all details for only one student

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM student, course, ProgCourse, programme;
```

any idea ?

I have `stu_id` but when I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT stu_id FROM student, course, ProgCourse, programme;
```

i only get the user id... how would i get all the data but just for one user id?

**Update**:
I have for tables `course`, `ProgCourse`, `programme`, and `student`

`course` has three columns `Course_id`, C_name and C_description  (course_id is prim)

`programme` has `Prog_id` and `P_name`  (Prog_id is prim)

`ProgCourse` has `Prog_id` and `Course_id`(both are foreign)

`student` has `stu_id`, `F_name`, S_name and Prog_id (Prog_id is a foreign key)(stu_id is a prim)

Fixed with:

```
SELECT * FROM student, course, ProgCourse, programme WHERE `S_name` = 'cook'; // cook is a individual surname
```

Comment: do you have his ID or name or something? You made typo, DISTINCT not DESTINCT

Comment: Please include your database structure. How do those tables reference eachother? You'll probably need to use some JOINs.

Comment: I think you have to filter on the specific student using the WHERE clause

Comment: I've nominated for re-opening in lieu of the edit.

Comment: SELECT * FROM student, course, ProgCourse, programme WHERE student.stu_id = id

Comment: With poor infos, we can also do : SELECT * FROM student, course, ProgCourse, programme WHERE student.name = "Beep"; or whatever this way...And not sure DISTINCT clause is useful here

Comment: @user2196728 still brings up all students rather than one stu_id.

Comment: I don't understand what you want : you want all column for a given student, or just the stud_id for a given student ? anything else ? And please tell us more about your DB structure because the only thing we can do now is to guess your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled `DISTINCT` wrong in your query

Edit:

```
SELECT * FROM student, course, ProgCourse, programme WHERE student.stu_id = stu_id
```

Comment: ive corrected the typo, that was a stupid mistake, however the problem still stands.

Comment: @Beep I need your db schema to update my answer. PK -> FK relationship please!

Comment: Updated my answer, for some reason I thought you needed a JOIN, but a simple WHERE clause should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for editing. What is the relationship of students to courses? Your query seems to return all courses, regardless of the student id. As you mentioned before, we need to know the relationships in order to build a functional query.